# Find $A^{-1}$ if $AB^TC = I_n$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are invertible $n \times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Find $A^{-1}$ if $AB^TC = I_n$.

My answer is $A^{-1}B^{-T}C^{-1}$, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: What is $B^{-T}$?

Comment: How did you come up with $A^{-1}B^{-T}C^{-1}$? Are you just writing stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously $$AB^TC=I_n$$ $$A^{-1}AB^TC=A^{-1}I_n$$ 
And at last $$A^{-1}=B^TC$$ 
You can do all of these operation because the three matrices are invertible, that is $A,B,C\in GL(n,\mathbb{K})$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field.

Moreover $AA^{-1}=I_n$ and $A^{-1}I_n=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$AB^TC=I$$
Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ from left:
$$A^{-1}AB^TC=A^{-1}I$$
Use the fact that $M^{-1}M=I$ and $MI=M$:
$$IB^TC=A^{-1}$$
Use the fact that $IM=M$:
$$B^TC=A^{-1}$$